# Hosted layer in ArcGIS not getting updated

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

I'm encountering a peculiar issue while trying to add records to a Hosted Layer in ArcGIS using Python.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3 with ArcGIS Enterprise 11.1. I am running this code from the Jupyter Notebook available in ArcGIS Pro only.

My workflow involves gathering necessary data from a service layer and an ArcGIS Pro geodatabase, which I access through a ".sde" connection. After retrieving the data, I perform several operations including merging datasets, renaming columns, and ensuring the data schema aligns with the requirements of the hosted layer. These steps involve the use of Python libraries such as ArcGIS, ArcPy, and Pandas.

The script executes without any errors, and the logs indicate a "success" message when adding data. However, upon inspection of the hosted layer, I observe that the data is not updated as expected. This has left me puzzled, as there are no indications of errors or failures in the script's execution process.

Could the community review my code and provide insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong?

I'm sharing the relevant portions of my code below for reference.

```
fc = r'path_to_data\abc.sde\table'

fields = ['*']

data = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields)]
columns = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if field.name in fields or fields == ['*']]
df_sde = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)

# Creating a GIS instance
gis = GIS('<gis_portal>', username, password)

service = '<service_layer>'
hosted = '<hosted_layer>'

# Connecting to the services

fabric_service = FeatureLayerCollection(service, gis)
fabric_hosted = FeatureLayerCollection(hosted, gis)

service_layer = fabric_service.layers[num1] 
hosted_layer = fabric_hosted.layers[num2]

## Importing the records as dataframe
service_records = service_layer.query(where="<some condition>", as_df=True, return_geometry=True)

## Truncating all the data in the hosted layer
try:
    logging.info("Starting data truncation process for the hosted layer.")
    result = hosted_layer.delete_features(where="1=1")
    if result['deleteResults']:
        logging.info("Data truncated successfully.")
    else:
        logging.warning("No data was deleted.")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Error occurred while truncating data: " + str(e))

## Importing the hosted layer data just to get the column names and schema. It results in an empty dataframe with column names and corresponding to data types
hosted_records = hosted_layer.query(where="1=1", as_df=True, return_geometry=True)

# Function to modify geometries of the geometry column in sevice_records to match the geometry requirement in the hosted
def project_in_batches(geometries, in_sr, out_sr, batch_size=5000):
    projected_geometries = []
    for i in range(0, len(geometries), batch_size):
        batch = geometries[i:i + batch_size]
        projected_batch = project(geometries=batch, in_sr=in_sr, out_sr=out_sr)
        projected_geometries.extend(projected_batch)
    return projected_geometries

# Reproject the geometries from service layer to match the hosted layer's spatial reference in batches
projected_geometries = project_in_batches(geometries=service_records[<geometry_column>].tolist(),
                                          in_sr={'wkid':wkid1},
                                          out_sr={'wkid':wkid2})

# Replace the original geometries with the projected ones
service_records[<geometry_column>] = projected_geometries

def merging_service_sde():
    '''
    This function acts as introducing the columns that must be present in the hosted layer but don't have a corresponding column neither in service_records nor df_sde. After that, such columns are populatied by Null values for the time being.
    '''
    cols_service = [<columns in service_records>]
    
    cols_sde = [<columns in df_sde>]
    
    cols_ignore = [<columns in hosted_records that do not have a corresponding column neither in service_records nor in df_sde>]
    
    
    temp_df_record = pd.merge(service_records[cols_service], df_sde[cols_sde], 
                              how = 'left', left_on = col1, right_on = col2)

    # Setting columns in cols_ignore as Null
    for col in cols_ignore:
        temp_df_record[col] = pd.NA
    
    return temp_df_record
    
merged = merging_service_sde()

mapping = {<mapping dictionary that maps the column names in such a way that it is identical to the column names present in hosted_records>}

# Mapping the column names
merged = merged.rename(columns = mapping)

# Extra step to align the columna according to the order in hosted_records for better readability
merged = merged[hosted_records.columns]

# Aligning the data types
for column in merged.columns:
    if column in hosted_records.columns:
        desired_type = hosted_records[column].dtype
        merged[column] = merged[column].astype(desired_type)
        
## Handling the missing values

object_cols = merged.select_dtypes(include = ['object', 'string']).columns
num_cols = merged.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'Float64', 'Int32', 'Int64']).columns
date_cols = merged.select_dtypes(include = ['datetime64[ns]']).columns

merged[object_cols] = merged[object_cols].fillna('N')
merged[num_cols] = merged[num_cols].fillna(0)
merged[date_cols] = merged[date_cols].fillna('2000-01-01')

merged_spatial = merged.spatial.to_featureset()

batch_size = 100  
total_records = len(merged_spatial.features)
batches = [merged_spatial.features[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, total_records, batch_size)]

for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
    try:
        batch_feature_set = FeatureSet(features=batch, geometry_type=merged_spatial.geometry_type, 
                                       spatial_reference=merged_spatial.spatial_reference)
        update_result = hosted_layer.edit_features(adds=batch_feature_set)
        success = list(set([i['success'] for i in update_result['addResults']]))
        if len(success) == 1 and success[0] == True:
            logging.info(f"Batch {i+1}/{len(batches)} added successfully")
        else:
            logging.info(f"Batch {i+1}/{len(batches)} not added")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error adding batch {i+1}/{len(batches)}: {e}")
```

Comment: You have presented what appears to be a copy/paste of a large chunk of your code rather than a code snippet that includes just its imports and enough code to be run to illustrate what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.

Comment: @PolyGeo This is all the code. Actually, this code runs without any errors and my logs are reported successful completion. But when I open the ArcGIS online and manually inspect the layer, I don't see any data added. That is why I got all my code here to check what I am doing wrong. I have not been able to figure out at all.

Comment: Where are you running this code from?  Telling us that may explain the absence of your imports and point at avenues for investigation. What versions of ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Enterprise are you using?

Comment: I apologize for the oversight. I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3 version. I am running this code form the Jupyter Notebook available in ArcGIS Pro only. The main imports that I am using are arcgis, pandas, and arcpy.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Enterprise are you using?

Comment: The version is 11.1. Does it have a lot of differences depending upon the version?

Comment: Keeping ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Enterprise versions contemporary is recommended wherever possible.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you for that. Do you think that there is something wrong with the code though?

Comment: If I were testing it I would remove the try/except statements to see if they are hiding any otherwise useful messages, and then start trying to reduce the code to a snippet that still reproduces the behaviour you say is unexpected.

Comment: If working on this in Pro Notebook environment have you verified that the delete operation towards the beginning is working correctly? Also it may be good in future development cycles to get all of your definitions in the beginning and then execute/call the functions all together at the end.